# SVN errors E170013, E120190 - An error occurred during authentication

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, subversion

I am trying to connect to my company SVN server in Ubuntu 16.04 and keep getting the following errors:

```
$ svn list https://path_to_repo
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://path_to_repo'
svn: E120190: Error running context: An error occurred during authentication
```

Note that normally everyone else in the company is using Windows to access the server and I am using Linux because of embedded development (of which I am the only one...).
The SVN server runs on Windows so I was wondering if there is something missing from the server configuration on Windows that would prevent access from a Linux machine. For what it's worth, I am able to connect to the VisualSVN server and view files. I just can't use any `svn` commands from the command line without getting the errors mentioned earlier.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I use VisualSVN server just fine with a linux client.  What happens if you `svn list --user <USER> --password-from-stdin https://path_to_repo`?

Answer (score 0):

Change the Authentication process to Basic from Integrated on Visual SVN Server.

Comment: (1) This answer would be better if it included instructions for how to do that.  (2) Note that the OP is talking about their work environment, so it’s quite possible (quite likely) that they don’t have privileges to change the server configuration.  Moreover, things are working fine for everybody else, so IT Support may be reluctant to make such changes.  Can you provide evidence that your suggestion will solve the OP’s problem and not break the system for all the other users?    Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.